# How can I make Conda find cc1plus?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, path, conda

When I am compiling a package on Ubuntu, I am getting this **error**

`x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory`

All my necessary libraries are in a conda environment named **CUSENV**

## Diagnosis

After conda environment activation:

1. `find /usr -name "cc1plus"`

`/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/cc1plus`

2. I can also see this executable:
   `/home/ms/anaconda3/envs/CUSENV/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.5/cc1plus`
3. `echo $PATH`

`/home/ms/anaconda3/envs/CUSENV/bin:/home/ms/anaconda3/bin:/home/ms/anaconda3/bin:/home/ms/anaconda3/bin:/home/ms/anaconda3/bin:/home/ms/anaconda3/condabin:/home/ms/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`

**How can I connect this cc1plus correctly?**

Comment: I'm stuck with this same issue right now.

Comment: any update on this? did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 8):

you should first install g++

```
conda install -c conda-forge gxx_linux-64
```

then

```
cd /home/ms/anaconda3/envs/CUSENV/bin
ln -s /home/ms/anaconda3/envs/CUSENV/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-g++ g++
```

Comment: Installing gxx_linux-64 worked for me. A similar solution is described here:
https://github.com/conda/conda-build/issues/3080